# Multivariate Taylor expansion of a $C^2$ function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

If we want to make a Taylor expansion of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ around a point $\mathbf a=(a_1, a_2)$,
then $f$ has to be analytic. Does there exist a variant of the multivariate Taylor expansion that applies to, for example, $f \in C^2$?

Comment: You can do a taylor expension up to degree 2, but you obviously, you can't find the Taylor series since - as you mentioned - the function need to be analytic.

Comment: But am I allowed to use the truncated Taylor series up to degree 2 at all, since $f$ is not analytic?

Comment: of course ! Why don't you try to prove it ?

Comment: Do you have a hint? As far as I understand, I have to start from the Taylor expansion theorem for an analytic f. I think that if I want to restrict that theorem to C^k functions, I have to understand the proof of the original theorem first.

Comment: The situation is exactly the same as in 1D with exactly the same proof once you add the small trick of looking at the line segment between x and x+h

Answer (score 1):

If $f \in C^2$, the best you can do is Taylor's formula... not a series expansion.

$$
f(x) = f(a) + f'_{x_1}(a) (x_1-a_1)+f'_{x_2}(a)(x_2-a_2)+(x-a)^T H(\xi) (x-a),
$$

where $H$ is the Hessian matrix and $\xi \in (x,a)$